# Creating multiple records from a single message layout using C#

Tags: c#

How do I create multiple records from a single message layout in C#? Say I have a message called MSG1 and it contains 5 fields, FLD1 - FLD5.  Where FLD4 and FLD5 need to be unique for each occurrence of the message.  Now I want to make 10,000 or 1 Million, what would be my best approach?

Example:

```
**MSG1**
FLD1:   20140227
FLD2:   ABCD
FLD3:   BUICK
FLD4:   ID0000000001
FLD5:   REG0000000001
```

Comment: Should FLD4 and FLD5 be unique based on the contents of the other fields, or just a unique id?

Comment: What is a C# message layout?

Answer (score 0):

I have coded this very simplistically based on your explanation. Following code might provide you starting point.

```
namespace GenerateMillionTags
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = Message1.CreateMessages(10000);

        // Do whatever you want with the list.
    }
}

public class Message1
{
    public string fld1_ { get; set; }
    public string fld2_ { get; set; }
    public string fld3_ { get; set; }
    public string fld4_ { get; set; }
    public string fld5_ { get; set; }

    public Message1()
    {
        fld1_ = @"20140227";
        fld2_ = @"ABCD";
        fld3_ = @"BUICK";
    }

    public Message1(string fld1, string fld2, string fld3)
    {
        fld1_ = fld1;
        fld2_ = fld2;
        fld3_ = fld3;
    }

    public static List<Message1> CreateMessages(uint count)
    {
        var messageList = new List<Message1>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            // here ids can be made/formatted as sophisticately as you want.
            messageList.Add(new Message1() {fld4_ = "ID" + i, fld5_ = "REG" + i});
        }

        return messageList;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes thats correct. But I tried to answer the question. Question looked simple and we can create complicated solutions and structure as a solution but you question didnt seem to demand it.

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment